# How to Display a Pie Chart in a table with the value of 2 columns in SRSS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

First, sorry for the title, but I couldn't think of a better one.

This is what I want to do.

I have a Tablix in SRSS 2008.  The rows are employees. In it I have 2 columns:

- TalkTime
- HoldTime

Which are integers, and the value is in seconds.

I want to add a column in the Tablix with a Pie Chart (yes, little) in order to graphically show the proportion of TalkTime vs. HoldTime. I don't want any titles, legends, etc., but just a quick visual: if the talk time was 750 seconds and the hold time was 250 seconds it should show 3 quarters and 1 quarter in the pie, in blue and red, say. You get the point.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done, but not in the Detail line.
If you want to add the chart to the detail line, add some grouping to the detail line (in such a way that the report still functions as before).

You can add the chart to a cell in the table, delete the tile and ledgend,add Talk time and hold time to the Values in chart data.

Comment: pardon my ignorance. I really don't follow. Let me try to start with something easier for me... In this tablix - as I said before - the row are employees. So I have totals at the bottom of the tablix: sum(TalkTime) and sum (HoldTime). I want a pie chart with those 2 values. I don't know how to do that, because it's not like a series.

Comment: I think I understand Does this RDL help https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1V23fERfaq7Z2Y3bTlNLVdSaEk

Comment: You are a genius! Thanks to your file I could figure out how to have 2 series. Thanks a lot!!!