# How to Display beyond 24 hrs in SSRS 2008 in HH:MM:SS format

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report in SSRS 2008 that pulls data from a table with a column, TotalTime that is an Integer value in seconds.

To display is as time I use this in the expression:

```
=Format(DateAdd("s", Fields!TotalTime.Value, "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")
```

(got that from here: [Display Seconds Count in HH:MM:SS format in SSRS 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481890/display-seconds-count-in-hhmmss-format-in-ssrs-2008))

Now, when the value goes beyond 24 hrs it does kind of a "module" value. I mean this: if the value would be 29 hrs, instead of displaying 29:00:00 it will display 05:00:00. If the value if 51 hrs, it will display 03:00:00 (takes out 48 hrs).

How do I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just add the amount of days?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 86,400 seconds in a day. So just use days if the seconds are greater than that:

```
=IIF(Fields!TotalTime.Value < 86400, 
    Format(DateAdd("s", Fields!TotalTime.Value, "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss"), 
    Floor(Fields!TotalTime.Value / 86400) & " days, " & Format(DateAdd("s", Fields!TotalTime.Value, "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: BTW, Chris, maybe you know this one too!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531567/how-to-display-a-pie-chart-in-a-table-with-the-value-of-2-columns-in-srss-2008

Answer (score 5):

For HH:mm:ss format you can use this:

```
=Floor(Fields!TotalTime.Value / 3600) &":"& Format(DateAdd("s", Fields!TotalTime.Value, "00:00"), "mm:ss")
```

In this case, for example 90000sec will be displayed as: **25:00:00**

For DD:HH:mm:ss format use this:

```
Floor(Fields!TotalTime.Value / 86400) &":"& Format(DateAdd("s", Fields!TotalTime.Value, "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")
```

90000sec will be shown as: **1:01:00:00**

Answer (score 1):

You really need to use the hour based solution, the day based one can potentially get you into trouble with Daylight Savings Time change overs.

```
=Floor(Fields!TotalTime.Value / 3600) &":"& Format(DateAdd("s", Fields!TotalTime.Value, "00:00"), "mm:ss")
```

Comment: This is exactly what @Konza posted for an answer.