# How to assign time values beyond 24 hrs to horizontal stacked bar chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a horizontal stacked bar chart with datetime on X-axis and certain names on Y-axis, like below:

[image: Horizontal stacked bar chart]

The graph bars takes time duration as values (HH:mm:ss). The problem is when there is a time duration value greater than 24 hours; for example, 32:15:42 (which is difference of two datetime values), it takes 11:15:42.

The problem is how to assign time values which are beyond 24 hrs?

Comment: Hello, is the question description good enough to describe the problem? Please let me know if anything is required. Thanks.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking. You might need to explain what datatypes are being used, how are you getting the duration values, how are they stored etc. Also look at this question with a similar title. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534686/how-to-display-beyond-24-hrs-in-ssrs-2008-in-hhmmss-format

Comment: Nice chart, but that doesn't show the problem. How did you calculate the difference and why did you calculate a `time` instead of a `datetime`?

Comment: Each bar indicates different process stage duration.I have used datetime datatype. I do have start datetime and end datetime for every process stage in database. What I have tried that to assign end  datetime of each stage but it's working, only two bars were shown with correct data for first bar(other bars were neglected). So I set expression to (Fields!FirstStage_end_date_time.Value - Fields!FirstStage_start_date_time.Value). Its working fine for value less than 23:59:59, for beyond 24 hours simply time difference. For eg. if resultant time value is 25:15:20 then it takes as 01:15:20.

Comment: I hope this description is helpful to resolve the problem. Correct me if I have done wrong. @WolfgangK could you please guide me how to assign "datetime" values insted of "time difference" values here. Thanks.

Comment: @testmestech You could maybe  use the difference in seconds instead: `=DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, FirstStage_start_date_time.Value, Fields!FirstStage_end_date_time.Value)`

Comment: @WolfgangK I have tried that, but facing same problem, what if seconds exceeds 24 hours duration, as bar takes values in "HH:mm:ss" time format only.

Comment: @testmestech Please amend your post and add a script to create sample data. I think that the values on the horizontal axis are sums, not intervals on a time axis.

Comment: Hello, I was using stacked bar chart, then I suddenly realised this can be possible with range bar chart with "DrawSideBySide=False". Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is use range bar chart with the property

> DrawSideBySide

set to

> False